# Java move <Preference> from one PreferenceScreen to another?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do something similar to iOS editable UITableView. I have a list of "added items" if the user clicks on "Add new item" he is taken to a PreferenceScreen with multiple `<Preference>` elements, onclick the should disappear from this screen and add it to the "Added list" (actually a `<PreferenceCategory>`), then they should be able to remove them from here or edit their order. This is similar to iOS editable lists.

[image]

This is my XML:

```
<PreferenceScreen android:title="ALL APPS" android:key="app_list">  
    <!-- A <preference> for each app -->
</PreferenceScreen>
<PreferenceCategory android:title="ADDED APPS" android:key="my_apps_list">
</PreferenceCategory>
```

I have tried uncountable times and I cannot get it to work.

How can I get it done?

Comment: i'm not so familiar with IOS and with what you wish to achieve . would you please show the problem in a more visual way ?

Comment: I added an image from iOS, I'll take a screenshot from my APP too.

Comment: what is the expected behavior (before , the trigger of the event, and after) ?  if it has nothing to do with preferences , it looks like a simple case of a listView , which you can learn about from the API documentation and from the "the world of listView" lecture made by google .

Comment: I just added a couple of screenshots showing the behavior. It actually works, except it doens't remove the item from the PreferenceScreen

Answer (score 2):

I've experimented around a bit and it's actually very easy when you nest your `PreferenceScreens`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Check it!" />

    <PreferenceScreen android:title="To the other preferences!" android:summary="I really hope this works &lt;3" >
        <EditTextPreference android:title="Edit your name" android:summary="Edit your name :)" />
        <CheckBoxPreference android:title="Accept answer" />
    </PreferenceScreen>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

[image]

PS: Please excuse my hard-coded string literals - it was just for testing! :)

Answer (score 0):

this looks like a very similar question to what i've asked in the past:

[android - showing listView in PreferenceActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616317/android-showing-listview-in-preferenceactivity)

when selecting the items to show , store them in some way (DB ,references ,etc...) and then use the solution i've found .

as you can see , the view used in preference activity is actually a listView , so it's weird to put a listView in a listView . what you need is a special trick , and that's something i've written about .

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look to the accepted answer on this question:

[How to remove Android preferences from the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081533/how-to-remove-android-preferences-from-the-screen)

Sometimes, if categories are present, you have to

> "reference the category containing the preference you wanted to remove and then remove that preference from that category"

like the answer there says. Isn't this also your case?

Hope this helped.