# show and hide preferences in android

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have a preference.xml file, and I want to show or hide some of the entry of this file.
But the problem is that the preferences aren't hidden.
My code is the following:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

        Preference customPref = (Preference) findPreference(getText(R.string.about));
        customPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
        Preference termAndConditions = (Preference) findPreference(getText(R.string.term_and_conditions));
        termAndConditions.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
        Preference privacyStatement = (Preference) findPreference(getText(R.string.privacy_statement));
        privacyStatement.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
        Preference login_with_facebook = (Preference) findPreference(getText(R.string.login_with_facebook));
        login_with_facebook.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
        Preference register_new_account = (Preference) findPreference(getText(R.string.register_new_account));
        register_new_account.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
        Preference login = (Preference) findPreference(getText(R.string.login));
        login.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
        Preference my = (Preference) findPreference(getText(R.string.my));
        my.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
        Preference miles_and_more = (Preference) findPreference(getText(R.string.miles_and_more));
        miles_and_more.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
        Preference voucher_booking = (Preference) findPreference(getText(R.string.voucher_booking));
        voucher_booking.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
        Preference invite_friends = (Preference) findPreference(getText(R.string.invite_friends));
        invite_friends.setOnPreferenceClickListener(this);
    }
onResume{
buildLogin()
}

private void buildLogin() {
        PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen = getPreferenceScreen();
        hidePreferences(preferenceScreen, R.string.my);
        hidePreferences(preferenceScreen, R.string.miles_and_more);
        hidePreferences(preferenceScreen, R.string.voucher_booking);
        hidePreferences(preferenceScreen, R.string.invite_friends);
    }
private void hidePreferences(PreferenceScreen preferenceScreen,
            int preferenceKey) {
        Preference customPref = (Preference) findPreference(getText(preferenceKey));
        preferenceScreen.removePreference(customPref);
    }
```

the idea is to hide some of the preferences on onResume(). This class is extending from PreferenceFragment. Can some one please point what am I  doing wrong. None of the preferences are hidden.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081533/how-to-remove-android-preferences-from-the-screen?rq=1

Comment: You max have to use the preference category instead of `preferenceScreen`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2240326/remove-hide-a-preference-from-the-screen